# Why rm does not delete files?

Tags: wildcard, rm, locate

I issue the following command:

```
Input:  locate libboost
Output: /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization-mt.so
        /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization-mt.so.1.53.0
        /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization.so
        /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization.so.1.53.0
```

Then I navigate to `/user/lib64` and issue the command `rm -f libboost*`. However, when I issue `locate libboost` again, I still the the same output that is printed above. Why `libboost` files are not deleted?

Comment: Assuming those files are folders, you'll need the flag -r(recursive)`rm -rf libboost*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locate command does not reflect the current status. It refers to a database, which is updated from time to time. You can trigger the update with the command updatedb. After the update, locate will not display these files anymore.